# Backup server external backup

Tags: centos6.5

I have a 4TB External HDD and i converted this HDD file system as ext3
i want to know how can i take backup of backup server using this HDD
i have already a 3TB HDD(with power), in that i could able to take backup 
which is an ntfs file system.
in this new HDD i have seen its a GPT file system and now i partitioned this and change it as ext3
if anybody needs further information i can give..
Please help to find out a way...

Answer (score 0):

If you want a fairly simple backup then you can use [rsync](https://www.samba.org/ftp/rsync/rsync.html). If you want a more sophisticated backup then [rsnapshot](http://rsnapshot.org/) will likely work.